# Fixed Header Grid View ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, gridview

I gone through lots of examples for fixed header grid view, and tried few options using div and java scripts. the one i didnot work from the example,  is there anything i miss here.

```
 CSS 
.gridViewHeader
{
     background-color:Navy;
    color:blue;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
   top:expression(<%= gv.HeaderRow %>.offsetParent.scrollTop-2);
}

design source
<table>
<tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" CellPadding="4" PageSize="50" RowHeaderColumn="True"
            AllowPaging="True" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderStyle="None"
            BorderWidth="1px" CssClass="gridViewHeader">
            <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#003399" BorderStyle="Inset" HorizontalAlign="Center"
                VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenfield1" runat="server"  />
    </asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
<HeaderStyle CssClass="gridViewHeader" />
```

For your sample

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" CellPadding="4" PageSize="50" RowHeaderColumn="True"
            AllowPaging="True" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderStyle="None"
            BorderWidth="1px" >

            <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridViewHeader" />

            <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#003399" BorderStyle="Inset" HorizontalAlign="Center"
                VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: thank you Candie for your ans, i tried that option but the header also moves up not fixed

Comment: i'am happy to help you but i in this case i think that you have problem with your css, because <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridViewHeader" />
 is the good answer

Answer (score 1):

This CSS will fix your problem:

```
.GVFixedHeader { font-weight:bold; background-color: Green; position:relative; 
             top:expression(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.scrollTop-1);}
```

Comment: i tried this option, but the header also moving, it freezes the <table> just above the grid view <div>

Comment: what explorer you are using ? in case header is moving then remove the top:expression and use
.GVFixedHeader { font-weight:bold; background-color: Green; position:relative; }

Answer (score 0):

I just did this very thing. I used this article as a reference.

http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/07/scrollable-gridview-fixed-headers-asp.html

The trick is to create a table and then place the grid inside a div just under the that table. Set the width of the detail cells the same width as the cells in the gridview. Then make sure the scroll bar stays on and then the grid and the table will line up in the event there are not enough rows to actually need the scrolling function.

Comment: hello, this option gives mismacth in width of the header and row details. the headers and columns are created dynamically. the headers and detail columns are not aligned properly

Comment: right you have to define the width of each result in the gridview in order to make it line up properley.