# Asp.net fixed headers during scroll in c#

Tags: gridview

I tried a lot of links that I found online including one in stack overflow:

[Fixed Header Grid View ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163402/fixed-header-grid-view-asp-net)

But none seem to work.

Does anyone have a solution ?

Comment: Any solution anyone ??

Comment: Could you explain us why these solutions don't work? Show us how you try to implement at least one of them, and show us what goes wrong. Then, we will be better able to help you.